# Looping through a table in php to find best spot to fit my data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, sorting

After running a mysql query I get the list containing data in a following form:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["event_id"]. " - timestamp: ". $row["event_start"]. " " . $row["event_duration"] . "<br>";
     }
}
```

Basically each row has three fields:

```
event_id   |   event_start   |   event_duration
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to iterate in php through the returned rows and find a place where I can put new event with some event_start timestamp and event_duration. The place that I'm looking for has to be free and ready to be filled with the event_id through its whole event_duration.

Quick example: let's say in the database I've got 4 events:

```
e1 starts at 1:00:10 and lasts 30 seconds

e2 starts at 1:00:40 and lasts 20 seconds

e3 starts at 1:01:30 and lasts 40 seconds

e4 starts at 1:02:50 and lasts 20 seconds.
```

Now I want to insert the e5 that lasts 20 seconds, so the perfect spot would be between e2 and e3, so after I provide the id of e5 and its duration, I would like to receive the timestamp of where can I put it (in my example it would be 1:01:00). How can I make a loop in php like this?

**Edit:**

the Select query that returns the data for me is as follows:

```
select event_id, event_start, event_duration 
from table 
where event_start>= 'begin-boundary-time' 
    and event_start+ event_duration <= 'end-boundary-time'
```

Comment: *How can I make a loop in php like this?* I would guess you will need some code! So don't waste time and try something

Comment: I'd like to help you improve this question but I can't tell what it is you're trying to do here. Where does the "new event" e5 come from? What do the events represent? Why are you providing the id of e5 instead of letting MySQL handle it—is there some constraint or meaning to the id we should know about? Why choose the spot between e2 and e3 (30 second gap) over the spot between e3 and e4 (40 second gap) when the duration of the new event is only 20 seconds? Why not insert it before e1 or after e4 instead?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about looping through the data and finding a place to insert if you are truly using a MySQL database to store the events.  You can sort the information when you are looking at the events using an order statement in an SQL query.  This most likely (depending on the size, fragmentation, or indexes on the table) be faster than having a PHP loop running every time.  Your inserts will be more accurate since they won't be delayed looping through to find a slot.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, but I just don't know how exactly should I construct the query for that, I only did a select statement that returns values between two dates, but that's all - ordering data here would not be enough probably since there's still the problem with appending duration... see my edit for sql statement that I have so far :)